# Euler Characteristic of Spherical Polygon

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am a little confused on what the Euler Characteristic of an n-sided spherical polygon would be. Because the polygon is 3 dimensional, would it be considered to have 2 faces or 1? Following that, I would think that the Euler Characteristic would simply be equal to the number of faces as the number of edges and vertices are the same.

Comment: The number of faces is indeed $2$, but not "because the polygon is 3 dimensional". It's because a polygon, as a simple curve, separates the sphere into two regions, each of which counts as a "face". So, you're correct, the [Euler Characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) reduces to the number of faces, confirming that the characteristic of the sphere is $2$.